# Wear Os stack framework flutter

Tags: operating-system, wear-os, sony-smartwatch, wearables, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I've built a voice-driven android app that uses the android speech recognition API. I'm currently trying to convert the app to a wear-os version. I've included the speech recognition permission in the apps manifest and have initialized the speech recognition instance the same as I have in the mobile app (which works!). The app launches well, however when I begin the speech recognition I get the following error: E/SpeechRecognizer: no selected voice recognition service

I've tested on both a physical Galaxy 4 watch, and an API 30 wear-os emulator and the problem occurs with both devices. I've installed google assistant on the devices, and google assistants voice recognition works well. I can't find and voice input / speech recognition settings on the app. I'm not sure what next steps to take in debugging this.

I want voice recognition to be detected so that it can be used on Wearos